# XCode5 using iPhone for Development

Tags: c++, iphone, xcode, xcode5

I am trying to use my iPhone to test out my apps.  When I select to use my iPhone for testing, it says "No matching code signing identity found" then a bunch of other crap in small letters.

I can then select Cancel or Fix Issue, so I do Fix Issue.  I then get Join Program, Cancel, or Add...  I already have my appleID added to the members area in "add" selection but it still errors out.

I have tried Join a Program then it says its $100 a month just to do this.  Does it really cost money and that much or I am doing this the wrong way?

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to join the Developer Program to be able to test your app on an actual device, but it is a yearly fee ($ 99), not monthly.

This is just the way it is.

Comment: Does the program allow me to put my apps in the app store as well?

Comment: Yes, that is part of the program and also allows you to install beta versions of the OS on your devices (but that will be some time since iOS7 just released),

Answer (score 2):

You need to be a member of the iOS developer program to run your apps on your iOS device, and yes, the cost is $100 per year.

Comment: Interesting, I will get it for Christmas then :)